# Strange problem with System.Speech Speech Synthesizer

Tags: .net, windows, text-to-speech

I'm working on a program that includes speech synthesis.  A few weeks ago, I wrote the introductory

```
    using (SpeechSynthesizer s = new SpeechSynthesizer())
    {
        s.SetOutputToWaveFile("file.wav");
        s.Speak(textBox1.Text);
    }
```

program.  It worked just fine.  I crossed off "research speech synthesis" from my task list and moved on to other parts of the project.

Now I'm writing a real program, and trying to use this same basic block of code.  However, it is now failing on the `s.SetOutputToWaveFile` call.  It throws a PlatformNotSupportedException, with the following message: "No voice installed on the system or none available with the current security setting."

I'm on 32-bit Vista.  As far as I can tell, both programs have the same compiler settings.  Note that this is a Winforms app, and not ASP.Net or anything partially trusted.  I pulled up the original program in another instance of Visual Studio, and it still works just fine.

Any ideas?

Edit, 11/9/09:

I've added a bounty, and now even just this program:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (SpeechSynthesizer ss = new SpeechSynthesizer())
    {
        ss.Speak("Hello There");
    }
}
```

fails.  I'm guessing that there's some permission or something that I need to set, but I can't find it.  My other program - the initial, basic program that does exactly the same as this new one, still works.

Comment: What's the result of something like s.SetOutputToDefaultAudioDevice(), same problem?

Comment: s.Anything() throws the same exception.  Viewing s in the debugger watch window shows the same PlatformNotSupportedException error for every property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

can you compare with [WinDiff](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/159214) both .csproj file and look if they use the same stuff for the references?

Maybe one use a local file(in his own sub directory) while the other use a system file?

Comment: The working program was referring to System.Speech, while the non-working program was referring to Microsoft.Speech.  They had completely different references!  I already diffed the .csproj files looking for security differences and missed the different references entirely.